# How do I extend the built in configuration providers in .Net to add custom storage?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, configuration

We have a configuration XML database.  Rather than access this directly through the database API I'd like to extend .Net's configuration classes to add a custom storage provider.

I'm not sure where to start.  I've seen the Configuration Application Block but this seems to have been deprecated.  I'm using .Net 3.5.

Which classes should I look at?  Which interfaces do I need to implement?  Has this been done elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load arbitrary files into the configuration system, but you will need to use ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration passing a ExeConfigurationFileMap which includes you file.

But the file would need to be in .config format, using `<configuration>` as the root element, and `<configSections>` to define custom sections. Once this is in place subclassing `ConfigurationElement` et al. allows a high degree of structural flexibility or to just parse the element yourself (override `ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement`).

Alternately, use some abstraction. Have a custom element in the normal .configuration, with a configuration section handler that loads a file specified in the main .config.

Comment: Thanks.  I've also come across SettingsProvider today which seems to be a very simple way to add a custom settings provider to an app...any thought?

Comment: Settings is not an area I really use, mostly is just some code generation wrapper around .config to make accessing values by name a little easier. But blocks some of the options of System.Configuration (e.g. getting a Configuration instance from an arbitrary file, making per-user config updatable).